# How to add/remove css :hover with jQuery for slideToggle function?

Tags: jquery

I've got a `div` which shows when the user is clicking on a button with jQuery `slideToggle`. Everything works fine, my only problem is that I would like to keep the `button` on `:hover` state as long as the `div` is shown. Once the user clicks it again and the div is hidden, the button should be in the `non-hover` state again.

How can I do that?

This is how it looks: http://jsfiddle.net/Teo123/4DW7U/1/

HTML

```
<div class="travel_infobox" id="infobox_1">
    <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div class="travel_info">
    <a href="#" id="info_button_1">InfoBox</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".travel_infobox").hide();
    $("#info_button_1").click(function(e){
        $("#infobox_1").slideToggle(600);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.travel_info a{
    text-decoration : none;
    background      : url('../images/info_icon.png') no-repeat left top 0px;
    color           : #555;
    }

.travel_info a:hover{
    background      : url('../images/info_icon.png') no-repeat left bottom 0px;
    color           : #FF6C00;
    text-decoration : underline;
    }
```

Comment: with addClass() and removeClass()

Comment: jQuery doesn't have access to pseudo classes

Comment: You may want to do a addclass to your A href, that has your hover css. Then do a removeclass when its toggled again. Its allot of jquery change but should work as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hello add switch stat var

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var btn=true;
$(".travel_infobox").hide();
$("#info_button_1").click(function(e){
    $("#infobox_1").slideToggle(600);
    if(btn) {
        $('.travel_info a:hover').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        btn=false;
    }else{
       btn=true;
         $('.travel_info a:hover').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

addClass() and removeClass() also work like a charm  : )

Comment: Hello, I tried it in my temp as well as in the JSFiddle, but I couldn't make it work. But what I noticed is that you focused on the text-decoration, my main issue is actually the background image which changes also color on :hover. Could you try to make yours work in a JSFiddle?